# R jsonlite: export dataframe in a defined structure

Tags: r, json, dataframe, export, structure

In Python (json.dump(data, file) I export a dictionary to a json file, which has the following structure, when I open the file:

```
{"TA_ID": [1, 2], "feature": ["a", "b"]}
```

I import this dataframe with jsonlite into R. After some input I modify the dataframe (e.g. appending data) and export it with jsonlite:

```
TA_ID = c(1, 2, 3)
feature = c("a", "b", "c")
test_data <- data.frame(TA_ID, feature)
write_json(test_data, "Export.json", pretty = FALSE, unbox = FALSE)
```

Now when I look in my Export.json file I see the following structure:

```
[{"TA_ID":"1","feature":"a"},{"TA_ID":"2","feature":"b"},{"TA_ID":"3","feature":"c"}]
```

How do I get the original structure in my file? After modifying it should look like:

```
{"TA_ID": [1, 2, 3], "feature": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

I tried "pretty" and "unbox" in write_json, but I can't achieve the expected result. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it to `list` instead of `data.frame`.

```
test_data <- list(TA_ID = c(1, 2, 3),feature = c("a", "b", "c"))

test_data

$TA_ID
[1] 1 2 3

$feature
[1] "a" "b" "c"


write_json(test_data, "Export.json", pretty = FALSE, unbox = FALSE)
```

It gives,

```
{"TA_ID":[1,2,3],"feature":["a","b","c"]}
```